# Error al ejecutar un AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Tengo el siguiente **error** al utilizar **AsyncTask**

> method gettext must be called from the ui thread

Mi código:

```
private class EnviarCorte extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    public void onPreExecute(){
        //Antes de empezar
        Precarga.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void onPostExecute(Void unused){
        //Al finalizar
        finish();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
        SQLiteHelper basededatos = new SQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext(), null, null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase bd = basededatos.getWritableDatabase();

        registro.put("fecha", Fecha_actual.format(new Date()));
        registro.put("folio", Folio.getText().toString());
        registro.put("ubicacion", Ubicacion.getText().toString());
        registro.put("productor", Productor.getText().toString());
        registro.put("telefono", Telefono.getText().toString());
        registro.put("celular", Celular.getText().toString());
        registro.put("fruta", Fruta.getText().toString());
        registro.put("corte", TipoCorte);
        registro.put("caracteristicas", Caracteristicas.getText().toString());
        registro.put("estado", "1");

        //Operaciones
        return null;
    }
}
```

.

```
ContentValues registro = new ContentValues();
EditText Folio,Ubicacion,Productor,Telefono,Celular,Fruta,Caracteristicas;
```

Método `onCreate()`:

```
Folio = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.regFolio);
        Ubicacion = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.regUbicacion);
        Productor = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.regProductor);
        Telefono = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.regFijo);
        Celular = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.regCelular);
        Fruta = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.regFruta);
        Caracteristicas = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.regCaracteristicas);
```

> Solucion

```
EnviarCorte nuevocorte = new EnviarCorte();
            nuevocorte.execute(Fecha_actual.format(new Date()),
                                Folio.getText().toString(),Ubicacion.getText().toString(),
                                Productor.getText().toString(),Telefono.getText().toString(),
                                Celular.getText().toString(),Fruta.getText().toString(),
                                TipoCorte,Caracteristicas.getText().toString(),"0");

@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        SQLiteHelper basededatos = new SQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext(), null, null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase bd = basededatos.getWritableDatabase();

        registro.put("fecha", params[0]);
        registro.put("folio", params[1]);
        registro.put("ubicacion",params[2]);
        registro.put("productor", params[3]);
        registro.put("telefono", params[4]);
        registro.put("celular", params[5]);
        registro.put("fruta", params[6]);
        registro.put("corte", params[7]);
        registro.put("caracteristicas", params[8]);
        registro.put("estado",params[9]);

        bd.insert(basededatos.TABLE_CORTES, null, registro);
        bd.close();
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Hola Manuel y cual es el error que obtienes en la consola o logcat? trata de especificar tus preguntas y dar más detalles porque de otra forma tal vez sea cerrada, =(

Comment: Yo te recomiendo que no subas imagenes de tu codigo, copialo y pegalo, para que sea mas facil ayudarte

Comment: @Elenasys el error es el siguiente: `method gettext must be called from the ui thread`

Comment: He agregado una respuesta, tienes que realizar el llamado de getText() en el método onPostExecute(), revisa mi respuesta. @ManuelMorales

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a tu error:

> method gettext must be called from the ui thread

El problema es que se realizan operaciones en el hilo principal al tratar de modificar la UI desde el método `doInBackground()`, llamando el método `getText()`, lo cual es incorrecto,

```
 @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params){
        SQLiteHelper basededatos = new SQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext(), null, null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase bd = basededatos.getWritableDatabase();

        registro.put("fecha", Fecha_actual.format(new Date()));
        registro.put("folio", Folio.getText().toString());
        registro.put("ubicacion", Ubicacion.getText().toString());
        registro.put("productor", Productor.getText().toString());
        registro.put("telefono", Telefono.getText().toString());
        registro.put("celular", Celular.getText().toString());
        registro.put("fruta", Fruta.getText().toString());
        registro.put("corte", TipoCorte);
        registro.put("caracteristicas", Caracteristicas.getText().toString());
        registro.put("estado", "1");

        //Operaciones
        return null;
    }
```

tienes que realizarlo cuando termina la ejecución del `Asynctask,` en el método `onPostExecute(`), que es donde puedes realizar operaciones en el hilo principal :

```
   @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            registro.put("fecha", Fecha_actual.format(new Date()));
            registro.put("folio", Folio.getText().toString());
            registro.put("ubicacion", Ubicacion.getText().toString());
            registro.put("productor", Productor.getText().toString());
            registro.put("telefono", Telefono.getText().toString());
            registro.put("celular", Celular.getText().toString());
            registro.put("fruta", Fruta.getText().toString());
            registro.put("corte", TipoCorte);
            registro.put("caracteristicas", Caracteristicas.getText().toString());
            registro.put("estado", "1");

    }
```